# I have question in proving limits of increasing/decreasing sequence of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

1. if $A_{1}\subset A_{2}\subset\cdots$ then $\lim_{i\rightarrow\infty}A_{i} = \cup_{i = 1}^{i = \infty}A_{i}$
2. if $A_{1}\supset A_{2}\supset\cdots$ then $\lim_{i\rightarrow\infty}A_{i}=\cap_{i = 1}^{i = \infty}A_{i} $

How can I prove these two statement?
Finding rigorous proof is too hard to me

Comment: I thought this was more or less the definition of a limit of a sequence of sets. What is your definition?

Comment: @Arthur The definition is more general, for sequences of sets not necessarily increasing or decreasing. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_limit

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/204733/prove-the-limit-of-monotone-increasing-set-is-the-union-of-sets

Answer (score 0):

Part (1):

By definition,

$ \bigcup\limits_{i = 1}^\infty \ A_i = \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \ S_n $

where
$ S_n = \bigcup\limits_{i = 1}^n \ A_i $

It is obvious that
$
S_n = A_1 \cup A_2 \cup \ldots A_n = A_n 
$

Hence, it follows that
$ \bigcup\limits_{i = 1}^\infty \ A_i = \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \ A_n $

This proves the first part.

Part (2):

By definition,

$ \bigcap\limits_{i = 1}^\infty \ A_i = \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \ S_n $

where
$ S_n = \bigcap\limits_{i = 1}^n \ A_i $

It is obvious that
$
S_n = A_1 \cap A_2 \cap \ldots A_n = A_n 
$

Hence, it follows that
$ \bigcap\limits_{i = 1}^\infty \ A_i = \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \ A_n $

This proves the second part.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation!